# Calling test from another class of selenium in java

Tags: nullpointerexception, selenium-rc, junit3

This is my method which call a function from another class 
Selenium Setup is defined hear.

```
public void Transfer() throws Exception {
System.out.println("\nTransfer\n");
    selenium.open("/logon/user");
    selenium.windowMaximize();
    login obj1 = new login();
    obj1.testlogin();
            selenium.click("link=TRANSFERS");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("80000");
```

This is the another class which has the function to execute for the above caller. 
The above setup function has selenium object which should be called hear in library.

```
public class login extends SeleneseTestCase{


public void testlogin(){


    System.out.println("\nLogin\n");    
    selenium.type("companyID", "abcd");
    selenium.type("j_username", "xyz");
    selenium.type("j_password", "123456");
    selenium.click("submit_logon");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("80000");

    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
1) Transfer(test)java.lang.NullPointerException
    at login.testlogin(login.java:12)
    at test.Transfer(test.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.j
```

ava:212)
        at SampleSuite.main(SampleSuite.java:25)

I am trying to save all function's like login in an library and want to call them as per required in suite but i am unable to pass the pointer of selenium browser to the called function

Can anyone help me to resolve the error

Setup Code as follows :

```
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://abc.com/");
    selenium.start();
}
```

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: I am also unable to call "selenium" object from one file to another file in java.

Comment: Use this [Link][1] For your answer.

This is the same Issue I Faced 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832319/how-to-call-selenium-to-another-class-nullpointerexception/6843288#6843288

Comment: Use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832319/) for your answer. This is the same issue I faced (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832319/).

Answer (score 1):

Just for simplicity sake, you could basically pass the Selenium object once to your testlogin(Selenium selenium)or you can create a static variable of Selenium = globalinstance and assign it to a variable and create a wrapper in the class that you want to use in testlogin{selenium  globalinstance}. Hope this helps as simple solution.