# How to call Selenium to another class : NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-rc

How can we cal an object selenium to the other file which has half code of selenium.

In PHP i can by following code.

`login($this);` ----> `login($sel){  ..... }`

Can i do the same in Java as my selenium setup is in one file and the function which uses it is in another file can we pass the selenium to other as I am getting the NullPointerException.
Let me know if you want more details related to this.

**Update**

Library.java

```
public class Library extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public int Login() throws Exception {

        if (selenium.isElementPresent("companyID")) {
            selenium.type("companyID", "COMP");
            selenium.click("submit_logon");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("80000");
        }
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends Library {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://businessbanking.com/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    public void testAllTests() throws Exception {
        Library obj1 = new Library();
        obj1.Login();
    }
}
```

As per my observation selenium instance started on login file is not addressed to Library. I tried to pass "selenium" as parameter but failed, in Library i tried "super.setUp()" it also failed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post code. Preferably a simplified version of whatever you have that exhibits the problem, but any code at all that reproduces it would be helpful.

Comment: @Samir Talwar: I have posted the code the call goes to library and for selenium line it gives NullPointerException while execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
public void testAllTests() throws Exception {
    Library obj1 = new Library();
    obj1.Login();
}
```

With:

```
public void testAllTests() throws Exception {
    super.Login();
}
```

Since your Login class already extends Library it already has the Login() method present in it. What you are currently doing is creating a new Library object which does not run the `@Before` and hence the Selenium field is not initialised (in the new object).

When a subclass extends a base class it will inherit its methods. This is a fundamental Java and OOP concept.

Comment: Thanks Its really a good answer that I missed I have done lots of work around, I use to use this super for setup and used to fail Thanks a lot. One thing regarding the same i want to ask is can I extend more than one Library as I will have 5-6 Libraries for the same and will I will be able to use the same.

Comment: In Java it is only possible to extend a single baseclass. Interfaces are probably something you want to look into. Implementing an interface requires you to implement every method that is defined in the interface.

Comment: So your suggestion is, I should create a class of interfaces and implementation of those in different classes. Then I should extend the interface class so that I can access the functions from the implemented classes. If its wrong then please give example regarding the same.

Comment: It's possible to implement multiple interfaces, just not to extend multiple baseclasses. The best solution really depends on your requirement. Why do you feel you need multiple baseclasses in the first place?

Comment: See I have to call different functions(Tests) the count may go to 3000-4000 and I will separate them in classes according to modules. Many time we need to call function from different modules to collaborate and form one test case. So I want to inherit them. In Php I have used `requireonce` and added all libraries so I was able to call the function by creating object of that class. But this is not the case in JAVA I cant call the class as i have the above problem if done so.