# Java:How to call Implemented method from interface name

Tags: java

I don't know how interface works for my problem but I have read that its possible by interface [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832319/how-to-call-selenium-to-another-class-nullpointerexception)

Problem: I have created an interface which has All the declaration of the methods its around 3000+ I am implementing these methods in 3 different classes, now I want to call the methods from Interface in my main file, reason I can need any method from any class and I cant extend more than one class so i thought about using interface.

Can I do this Answers are appreciated.

Update: using extend I can use `super.methodName();` So that i am not creating an object. 
I can split these methods in different interfaces or different classes but I must access the methods without creating the object Please the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832319/how-to-call-selenium-to-another-class-nullpointerexception) to understand what i want to do.

Update2: `Interface ABC`  // `public int go()` function is declared here

```
Class XYZ implements ABC

method go(object imp)  
{.....}
```

Another class

```
Class PQR extends/implements ABC 
{
   // some code
   int ret = super.go(this); OR int ret = obj.go(this)
} // What Should I use I now ABC is my interface but dont know where is it implemented so i want to call the go function how can I do this Please Explain what should i use.
```

Thanks

Comment: 3000+ methods in the interface?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to split the implementation of your interface (3000 methods) over 3 different classes (1000 methods each) ? Or do you want to implement all of them in each of the 3 classes ? The first is impossible. The second is. However, there is clearly something wrong if you have 3000+ methods in a single interface.

Comment: If you have 3000+ methods (or lines, doesn't matter) in one interface... you're doing it wrong and you haven't understood the concept of Interfaces (or OOP). Also, if I understand you correctly, you should create 3 different interfaces instead.

Comment: @Barth: Well, you could use inheritance on classes, so it would work. nevertheless, it seems like strange code structure, you're right

Comment: @Donneo you are correct, I overlooked this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a method on an interface, it actually calls the implementing method on the concrete class.  It doesn't matter that you have an insane number of methods or how many classes you have. e.g.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.size(); // actually calls ArrayList.size()
```

BTW: There is only a relatively small number of classes which have 3000 lines, let alone 3000 methods. I assume this is generated code.

Comment: yes it is generated code but i have to pass browser instance to these classes so its possible by `super` keyword.

Comment: Using the `super` keyword doesn't make a difference to the caller of the interface.

Comment: Ya but I am implementing the code in other class and call that implementation in this class is it possible please help me with sample code `ABC` is interface with `go` method and i have implemented this method in `xyz` class now i want to use this implementation in `pqr`class with the help of `ABC` I dont know where the method is implemented

Comment: I am confused what the problem is; The method is implemented when you implemented it.  If you are using an interface the code doesn't need to know where it is implemented.

Comment: Then how should i call the function in above example in comment

Comment: PQR can only implement the interface. It can only call `super` on a method implemented in a parent class (not an interface).  To call the same method on another instance you can just call `obj.go()` but you have to have a reference to this object.

Answer (score 3):

Let be an interface Z and classes A and B implementing Z. Z has a method m1().

```
Z z1 = new A();
Z z2 = new B();
z1.m1(); // actually calls m1 as implemented in A even if the object is declared as Z.
z2.m1(); // different implementation of the same method m1
```

You **declare** z1 as being of type Z, but the **implementation** is A. Same thing for z2 but for B.

Answer (score 0):

If you're are talking about generated code I think what you need is to load a class at run-time. You can't call the methods of an interface without having those methods implemented in a concrete class and (without having) an interface "reference object" that points to an instantiated object (that implements that interface).

So a solution would be the use of Reflection, over which I suggest you take a look. This will give you an idea how to load a class, call methods and pass arguments at run-time, not at compile time. (i.e. you can call those methods after the dinosaur class was generated)

A small example can be found at: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/